# cascading multiple relationships

Tags: c#, nhibernate, relationships, cascading

I've got a fairly common scenario, I've got two tables that I'd like to relate together, specifically Country and Language.

I've specified my mappings like this:

```
public LanguageMapping()
{
    Table("Languages");
    Id(x => x.Id, "LANG_ID").GeneratedBy.Identity();
    HasMany(x => x.CountriesLanguages)
       .Cascade
       .SaveUpdate()
       .KeyColumn("LANG_ID");
}

public CountryMapping()
{
    Table("COUNTRIES")
    Id(x => x.Id, "COUNTRY_ID").GeneratedBy.Identity();
    HasMany(x => x.Languages)
       .Cascade
       .SaveUpdate()
       .KeyColumn("COUNTRY_ID"); 
}

public CountryLanguageMapping()
{
    Table("COUNTLANG");
    Id(x => x.Id, "COUNTLANG_ID").GeneratedBy.Identity();                                                
    References(x => x.Country,"COUNTRY_ID").Cascade.SaveUpdate().Not.Nullable();
    References(x => x.Language, "LANG_ID").Cascade.SaveUpdate().Not.Nullable();
}
```

So, this all looks fine. (note I've taken out the data for simplification). So I'm saying that the joining table must have both a country and a language to be valid, which seems fair enough.

In all scenarios I'm about to discuss, there is no data in the session.

If I do something like this, all is good.

```
var country = new DboCountry
{
    Name = "UK",
    Code = "GB",
};

var language = new DboLanguage()
{
    Code = "EN",
    Name = "English"
};

var countryLanguage = new DboCountryLanguage
{
    Country = country,
    Language = language,
    IsDefault = true,
    LanguageCode = "en-GB"
};

dataSession.Save(countryLanguage);
```

All good. But I don't always want to work like this. If I try to do it like the following, it breaks with an exception, implying that the language hasn't been set and I'm breaking the nullable constaraint..., even though I'd expect the cascade to handle this...

```
var language = new DboLanguage()
{
    Code = "EN",
    Name = "English"
};

var countryLanguage = new DboCountryLanguage
{
    Language = language,
    IsDefault = true,
    LanguageCode = "en-GB"
};

var country = new DboCountry
{
    Name = "UK",
    Code = "GB",
    Languages = new []{countryLanguage}
};

dataSession.Save(country);
```

and I get `NHibernate.PropertyValueException : not-null property references a null or transient value IDL.Common.ControlCloud.Orm.Dto.DboCountryLanguage.Country` Why is the cascade not picking up that it needs to populate the country foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is that what is clear on the level of relational DB must be explicitly set on the C# (entity) level.

We do have this clear defintion of the CountryLanguage

```
public CountryLanguageMapping()
{
    ...       
    References(x => x.Country,"COUNTRY_ID")
       ...      
       // here
       .Not.Nullable();
```

So, we instruct NHibernate:

> whenever there is a `CountryLanguage` instance, check that its reference `Country` is NOT null

But what we can see in the code is:

```
var language = ...
// create instance of CountryLanguage
var countryLanguage = new DboCountryLanguage
{
    Language = language,
    IsDefault = true,
    LanguageCode = "en-GB"
};
// at this moment the countryLanguage.Country == null
// we (I really mean we, not NHibernate) did not set that value

// next we do create Country
var country = new DboCountry
{
    Name = "UK",
    Code = "GB",
    Languages = new []{countryLanguage}
};
// and while we assigned that country will have some item in Languages collection
// the countryLanguage.Country is still null

// NHibernate cannot continue below
// because we did not fulfill the contract .Not.Nullable();
dataSession.Save(country);
```

The solution here is to explicitly set both directions (almost a golden rule)

```
var country = new DboCountry
{
    Name = "UK",
    Code = "GB",
    Languages = new List<CountryLanguage>{countryLanguage},
};
countryLanguage.Country = country;
```

Now NHibernate has enough info to proceed properly

Extend. If we do properly both relations in C# we also can improve the SQL *INSERT UPDATE* handling using the inverse setting:

```
Table("COUNTRIES")
Id(x => x.Id, "COUNTRY_ID").GeneratedBy.Identity();
HasMany(x => x.Languages)
   .Cascade
   .SaveUpdate()
   .KeyColumn("COUNTRY_ID")
   .Inverse() // here we go
   ;
```

That will instruct NHibernate to use more efficient SQL statements. But again it requires both sides of relation to be properly assigned in C#. Later, when objects are already in DB and then loaded by NHibernate, both relations will be set. This is job of NHibernate. But that happens during the READ from DB